# Python Turtle Spirals

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to draw a spiral after it has drawn the recursive squares 'k' number of times, and get my desired output -

however I'm confused with the spiral() function, and how to go about it to get that output.

code -

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import math


def squareinsquare(x, y, side):
    square(x, y, side)
    half = side / 2
    b = math.sqrt(half**2 + half**2)

    tiltsquare(x, y - side/2, b)

#squareinsquare(0, 0, 200)

def fractal(x, y, startSide, k):  
    t.setpos(x, y)
    for i in range(k):
        square(*t.pos(), startSide)
        t.forward(startSide / 2)
        t.right(45)
        startSide /= math.sqrt(2) 

fractal(0, 0, 200, 5)

def spl(x, y, stLength, k):  
    # YOUR CODE BELOW THIS LINE

s.exitonclick()
```

Comment: So you've shown us a bunch of code, but it's not the code you're asking your question about. What have you tried, with respect to drawing the spiral? What issues are you having? We're not going to write your code for you, but if you have an issue with your attempted solution, we can help with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given us any information on the logic of that spiral. How it is relates to the squares, etc ...

For what it's worth, this will replicate that top image, more or less.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import math

t = Turtle()
s = Screen()
t.speed(0)

def square(x, y, side):
    t.setpos(x,y)
    for i in range(4):
        t.forward(side)
        t.right(90)

def tiltsquare(x, y, side):
    t.left(45)
    square(x, y, side)

def squareinsquare(x, y, side):
    square(x, y, side)
    half = side / 2
    b = math.sqrt(half**2 + half**2)

    tiltsquare(x, y - side/2, b)

# squareinsquare(0, 0, 200)

def fractal(x, y, startSide, k):  
    t.setpos(x, y)
    for i in range(k):
        square(*t.pos(), startSide)
        t.forward(startSide / 2)
        t.right(45)
        startSide /= math.sqrt(2) 

fractal(0, 0, 200, 5)

#x,y are start point coordinates, stLength is len. of first move and k is number of moves  
def spiral(x, y, stLength, k): 
    t.up()
    t.setpos(x, y)
    t.seth(90)
    t.down()
    for i in range(k):
        t.forward(stLength)
        t.left(15)
        stLength -=0.2


spiral(250,-120,40,200)   

s.exitonclick()
```

[image]